# myFunction.call() not working with MetaMask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I can't seem to figure out why the function symbol() isn't working. I've made sure that MetaMask is on the right network (main net). I tried console.logging the myContract.methods... line and seem to get an error, but can't seem to figure out what it means.

[image: console.log showing error]

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var myContract;

  function startApp() {
     myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(crowdsaleABI, 
     "0x618E75Ac90b12c6049Ba3b27f5d5F8651b0037F6")
  };

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
     // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
     web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
     document.write("You are connected to MetaMask");
  } else {
     // Handle the case where the user doesn't have web3.
     document.write("You are not connected to MetaMask");
     web3 = new Web3(new 
     Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"));
  }
  // Now you can start your app & access web3js freely:
  startApp();

  myContract.methods.symbol().call().then((result) => 
  {console.log(result)});

  });

  /*ERROR DETAILS:
  "Error
  at A.R [as _captureStackTrace] 
  (http://localhost:3000/src/js/web3.min.js:1:350318)
  at A._then (http://localhost:3000/src/js/web3.min.js:1:373974)
  at A.then (http://localhost:3000/src/js/web3.min.js:1:372344)
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
  (http://localhost:3000/src/js/app.js:22:50)
  at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27449)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213)
  at Function.ready (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:30006)
  at HTMLDocument.K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:30368)"*/
```

EDIT: I also tried replacing web3.currentProvider with an Infura API to the main net and it actually worked. So it seems to be something with MetaMask, but I still can't seem to figure out what exactly.

Comment: Based on your edit, my guess would be that MetaMask isn't connected to mainnet, or the fallback is being reached and 127.0.0.1:7545 isn't connected to mainnet.

Comment: I tried using MetaMask with some other DApp and it responds just normal to it.

Comment: Which message do you see? "You are connected to MetaMask" or "You are not connected to MetaMask"? What software is running at 127.0.0.1:7545, and what network is it connected to?

Comment: It shows "You are connected to MetaMask". I'm running Ganache at 127.0.0.1:7545, so it's a private network.

Comment: If you're seeing "You are connected to MetaMask", then the private network shouldn't matter (but you might want to remove the `else` block just to be safe). I'd suggest inspecting `web3.currentProvider` to make sure it's MetaMask and double check once again that MetaMask is connected to mainnet. (Perhaps switch to a test network and then switch back.)

Comment: I've switched back and forth between test net and main net, but they both don't work. Only when I use Infura to connect does it actually work. I also made sure that MetaMask is injected by disabling the plug-in and running it.

Comment: Could you provide a full repro? Maybe the entire page hosted somewhere.

Comment: Here's a link (https://github.com/dkelsen/Crowdsale) to my project repository. I included the minimum repro steps in the README file that still result in the same problem (tried myself). The goal is to get the symbol of OmiseGo from the main net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using `document.write` is the problem. Switching to `console.log` in your repro fixes the problem for me.

I don't know *why* that causes a problem, but it's probably not worth spending too much time on. (`document.write` is considered a bad practice these days.)

**EDIT**

I should add that I saw different behavior from you. For me, the `Promise` never resolved one way or the other. (`then` and `catch` handlers didn't get called at all.) Removing the `document.write` calls resolved this for me.